Перенос таблиц с сайта в базу данных
Есть сайт, на котором находится много разных табличек по типу экселевских (таблицы содержат числовые значения, текст и изображения)
Мне надо как-то занести это всё в бд mysql
Не получается никак с этим справиться, пробовал спарсить, пробовал перегонять таблички в ворд и пдф и оттуда распознавать, но безрезультатно
Вопрос: Как мне занести в базу эти таблички таким образом, чтобы я мог с ними удобно работать?(под кодом sql таблицы приложил маленькое пояснение своей задачи)
Прилагаю скриншот таблицы на сайте
Также, прилагаю sql код таблички
CREATE TABLE welding.GOST16037_80 
(
  idPrmtr int(5) DEFAULT NULL,

  idDOC int(3) DEFAULT NULL,

  wj_symbol varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  picture1 mediumblob DEFAULT NULL,

  picture2 mediumblob DEFAULT NULL,

  weldingmethod varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  s int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  b_nomin double DEFAULT NULL,

  b_error_up double DEFAULT NULL,

  b_error_down double DEFAULT NULL,

  c_nomin double DEFAULT NULL,

  c_error_up double DEFAULT NULL,

  c_error_down double DEFAULT NULL,

  e_nomin double DEFAULT NULL,

  e_error_up double DEFAULT NULL,

  e_error_down double DEFAULT NULL,

  g_nomin double DEFAULT NULL,

  g_error_up double DEFAULT NULL,

  g_error_down double DEFAULT NULL,

  gamma double DEFAULT NULL,

  alpha double DEFAULT NULL

)

ENGINE = INNODB,

CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,

COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;

b_nomin (номинальное значение), b_error_up(верхний порог для отклонений), b_error_down(нижний порог для отклонений). Сделал так, потому что мне нужно будет получать значение параметра сварного шва и сравнивать с диапазоном допустимых по ГОСТу значений и на основании этого выносить вердикт, прошёл ли сварной шов контроль, или нет


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Пока максимальный результат- получилось парсить сайт, но не получилось спарсить именно нужную табличку, как бы не старался, заносится какой-то рандомный кусок сайта в базу, а не то, что мне нужно

Как спарсить любой сайт?

Если нет доступа к БД/файлам сайта - парсить.
Но картинки не писать в базу, а складывать в каталоги картинками. В базе писать пути (и др их данные по необходимости).
Если доступ есть - зависит от того как сделан сайт.

Есть какой-то пример, как вынести определенный фрагмент только с сайта?
Я типа написал метод, который запрашивал номер таблицы и по номеру должен был парсить, но там хрень какая-то получилась и я пока не понимаю, как работать с этим

Какой пример? Берёшь и разбираешь html конкретной страницы. Не понимаешь как парсить - есть масса доступных материалов, ищи, учись. Ну или фрилансеры наконец.
